# quanteda - find most frequent terms by percentages

Tags: r, quanteda

I often use the following codes to find the top-n features from the text:

```
    top_n_terms <- text %>% 
      tokens(remove_numbers = TRUE, remove_punct = TRUE, remove_symbols = TRUE) %>% 
      tokens_ngrams(n = 1:3) %>% 
      dfm() %>% 
      dfm_remove(stopwords("en")) %>% 
      topfeatures(n = 3000)
```

Moreover, I want to find the **top 10% features** with the xx% input instead of `n = xx`. How could I adjust the code?

Thank you a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function `nfeat()` to get the number of features. Multiply this with 0.1 and you can get it automatically. Or you can define a variable before this code where you specify the needed percentage.

See example below using data_corpus_inaugural. Using your selections this should have 190261 features, but using the code with the 10% selection it returns 19026 features.

```
top_n_terms <- data_corpus_inaugural  %>% 
  tokens(remove_numbers = TRUE, remove_punct = TRUE, remove_symbols = TRUE) %>% 
  tokens_ngrams(n = 1:3) %>% 
  dfm() %>% 
  dfm_remove(stopwords("en")) %>% 
  topfeatures(n = nfeat(.) * 0.1) # note the . in nfeat. replace 0.1 with variable if needed.
```

Comment: Thank @phiver for the suggestion. I have other questions that could be done with quanteda: 

1/ How could I check the parsing % after limiting the number of terms? 
2/ Instead of using the number of features, how could I set the parsing % (50%,) and let R return top features contributing to 50% text content of my corpus. 
Thank you in advance!